# Why am i getting the error java.lang.NullPointerException in my battleship game?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to code a battleship game and im getting a weird error when i run it:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Caculations.findShip(Caculations.java:29)
    at Board.main(Board.java:60)

Please help im stuck and i dont know how to continue! Here is my code: (Note, its in 2 class files in my eclipse work enviorment)

```
public class Board {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean continuePlay = true;
        int[][] board = new int[10][10]; // creating 2d array 'board'
        char[][] boardGraphical = new char[10][10]; // creating 2d array 'board
                                                    // this time the visual
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) { // for within for //initializing elements
                                        // in both boards using double for
                                        // method
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                board[x][y] = 0;
                boardGraphical[x][y] = 'o';
                System.out.println("Board element " + x + " " + y // printing
                                                                    // initialized
                                                                    // elements
                                                                    // here
                        + " initialized");
            }

        }

        /*
         * 1) Make user ships 1 and computer ships 2 (all numbers other than 0 =
         * true)
         * 
         * 2) Make it where if the computer gets a hit on a '1' than it sets
         * that value to like a 3 or something so it knows when the ship is
         * sunk. So in a if it does if([x][y] && [x][y])
         * System.out.println("You sunk my ship!");
         * 
         * 3) REMEMBER YOU CAN DO MULTIPLE IFS INSIDE IFS FOR MULTIPLE
         * CONDITIONS. 4) declare ships here!
         * 
         * 5) PUT STUFF IN A WHILE LOOP SO COMP CAN KEEP GOING
         */
        board[3][3] = 1; // declaring a battleship. Very important.
        board[3][4] = 1;
        board[3][5] = 1;
        boardGraphical[3][3] = 's';
        boardGraphical[3][4] = 's';
        boardGraphical[3][5] = 's';

        while (continuePlay == true) { // while loop so that computer keeps
                                        // guessing
            // WITHIN THIS LOOP KEEP REPRINTING THE BOARD
            double computerChoiceXd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // using
                                                                        // Math.random
                                                                        // functions
                                                                        // for
                                                                        // computers
                                                                        // first
                                                                        // guess
                                                                        // to be
                                                                        // a
                                                                        // random
                                                                        // num
            double computerChoiceYd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            int computerChoiceX = (int) computerChoiceXd;
            int computerChoiceY = (int) computerChoiceYd;

            if (board[computerChoiceX][computerChoiceY] == 1) { // checking if
                                                                // math.random
                                                                // landed on a
                                                                // ship point
                System.out.println("Computer got a hit at " + computerChoiceX
                        + " " + computerChoiceY);
                board[computerChoiceX][computerChoiceY] = 2; // setting the
                                                                // point as 2 or
                                                                // 'hit'
                boardGraphical[computerChoiceX][computerChoiceY] = 'H';
                for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) { // printing out graphical
                                                        // board using the same
                                                        // method as when
                                                        // intializing
                    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                        System.out.print(boardGraphical[row][col]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(" "); // spacer for printing
                }

                Caculations test = new Caculations(computerChoiceX, // Creating
                                                                    // a new
                                                                    // object of
                                                                    // calculation
                        computerChoiceY, board);
                test.findShip();
                // break;

                if (board[3][3] == 2) { // checking to see if ship is sunk using
                                        // a triple if statement
                    if (board[3][4] == 2) {
                        if (board[3][5] == 2) {
                            System.out.println("Battleship sunk!");

                            continuePlay = false; // if so than it breaks out of
                                                    // loop to end the game
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            } else if (board[computerChoiceX][computerChoiceY] == 0) { // otherwise
                                                                        // if
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // area
                                                                        // is a
                                                                        // 0 or
                                                                        // 'unmarked'
                System.out.println("Computer missed  at " + computerChoiceX
                        + " " + computerChoiceY);
                boardGraphical[computerChoiceX][computerChoiceY] = 'x'; // mark
                                                                        // area
                                                                        // as a
                                                                        // miss
                for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) { // print out board
                    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                        System.out.print(boardGraphical[row][col]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }

            }

        }

    }

}





public class Caculations {
    int xValue;
    int yValue;
    int[][] myArray;
    int[][] storage = new int[10][10];
    boolean xAxisChangeP;
    boolean yAxisChangeP;
    boolean xAxisChangeN;
    boolean yAxisChangeN;
    boolean notSunk;

    Caculations(int x, int y, int[][] myArray) {
        xValue = x;
        yValue = y;
        xAxisChangeP = true;
        yAxisChangeP = true;
        xAxisChangeN = true;
        yAxisChangeN = true;
        notSunk = true;

    }

    void findShip() {
        while (notSunk == true) {
            // 1
            while (xAxisChangeP == true) {
                if (myArray[xValue + 1][yValue] == 1) {
                    myArray[xValue + 1][yValue] = 2;
                    if (myArray[3][3] == 2) {
                        if (myArray[3][4] == 2) {
                            if (myArray[3][5] == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Battleship sunk!");
                                notSunk = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    xAxisChangeP = false;

                }

            }
            while (xAxisChangeN == true) {
                if (myArray[xValue - 1][yValue] == 1) {
                    myArray[xValue - 1][yValue] = 2;
                    if (myArray[3][3] == 2) {
                        if (myArray[3][4] == 2) {
                            if (myArray[3][5] == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Battleship sunk!");
                                notSunk = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    xAxisChangeN = false;
                }
            }

            // 1
            while (yAxisChangeP == true) {
                if (myArray[xValue][yValue + 1] == 1) {
                    myArray[xValue][yValue + 1] = 2;
                    if (myArray[3][3] == 2) {
                        if (myArray[3][4] == 2) {
                            if (myArray[3][5] == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Battleship sunk!");
                                notSunk = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    yAxisChangeP = false;

                }

            }
            while (yAxisChangeN == true) {
                if (myArray[xValue][yValue - 1] == 1) {
                    myArray[xValue][yValue - 1] = 2;
                    if (myArray[3][3] == 2) {
                        if (myArray[3][4] == 2) {
                            if (myArray[3][5] == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Battleship sunk!");
                                notSunk = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    yAxisChangeN = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you initialized myarray? Best is debug your code to see, which statement throws the exception. In eclipse you can add NullPointerExeption as your breakpoint and debug.

Comment: ........exactly! up-vote

Comment: up-vote for `In eclipse you can add NullPointerExeption as your breakpoint`

Comment: This is an answer guys... chill :)

Answer (score 2):

You use myArray, but you never initialize it.

```
public class Caculations {
   int xValue;
   int yValue;
   int[][] myArray;  // array declared but never initialized

   // ....

   void findShip() {
      while (notSunk == true) {
         // 1
         while (xAxisChangeP == true) {
            if (myArray[xValue + 1][yValue] == 1)  // then you use it here
```

Solution: initialize variables before using.

More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Thanks for the help Hovercraft! I really apreciate it. Also, ill deffinetly read up more about that. I actually just started Java from a book and I was just doing this for fun so I probably wasnt ready to atempt a complicated program like this.

Comment: Ok sorry i have a new problem, when i run it now after intializing the array it just gets 1 hit than freezes and dosnet execute anything more. If you get a chance could you please look at my code and help find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for `Calculations`, you never initialized `myArray`:

```
Caculations(int x, int y, int[][] myArray) {
    xValue = x;
    yValue = y;
    xAxisChangeP = true;
    yAxisChangeP = true;
    xAxisChangeN = true;
    yAxisChangeN = true;
    notSunk = true;
    this.myArray = myArray; //Add this line
}
```

This is a direct answer to your problem, but all in all, you should do some research regarding the meaning behind the exception that was thrown so you understand what it means.

---

### Why this problem happened

In Java, all objects and primitives, if not initialized manually, are given a default value.
For default values of primitives, check this: [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

In case of non-primitive types - such as `Object`, `String`, `Thread`, etc, as well as any user-defined class (i.e. `Calculations`) and also arrays (i.e. `myArray`) - the default value is `null`.

With that in mind, inside your constructor, as exemplified above, you have not initialized `myArray`, which means that when this variable was accessed for the first time, the value returned was `null`.

---

### So, what's the problem with `null`?

Well, by itself, it does no harm. It's there. It doesn't bother you. Until you decide to use a variable that doesn't have an object assigned to it, but somehow you forget that and treat it as if it held something like a `String` or an array.

That's when Java will tell you: **"Hey! There's no object here. I can't work like this. Let's throw an exception!".**

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much @victorantunes for such a thorough explanation. This really helps alot and it was nice of you to take the time and effort to read my code and give a great answer. I really  appreciate your help!